# Equation and subequations numbering in table environment

Tags: tables

I'm writing my thesis with latex and I have a problem with this table setting. I would like to have all the equations aligned on the left and also the first and the last rows less height.
Here is my code

```
\begin{table}\centering
\begin{tabular}{ m{3cm} m{10cm} }\hline
Continuity & {\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}+\nabla\cdot\left ( \rho\mathbf{V}\right ) 

=0\label{continuity_1}\end{equation}}\\
x-momentum\newline\newline y-momentum\newline\newline z-momentum & {\begin{subequations}\begin{align}
&\frac{\left ( \partial \rho u\right ) }{\partial t}+\nabla\cdot\left ( \rho u\mathbf{V}\right ) = -\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}+\nabla\cdot\left ( \mu\nabla u\right ) +S_{Mx}\\
&\frac{\left ( \partial \rho v\right ) }{\partial t}+\nabla\cdot\left ( \rho v\mathbf{V}\right ) = -\frac{\partial p}{\partial y}+\nabla\cdot\left ( \mu\nabla v\right ) +S_{My}\\
&\frac{\left ( \partial \rho w\right ) }{\partial t}+\nabla\cdot\left ( \rho w\mathbf{V}\right ) = -\frac{\partial p}{\partial z}+\nabla\cdot\left ( \mu\nabla w\right ) +S_{Mz}
\end{align}\label{NS_eq1}\end{subequations}}\\
Energy & {\begin{equation}
\frac{\left ( \partial \rho e\right ) }{\partial t}+\nabla\cdot\left ( \rho e\mathbf{V}\right ) =-p\nabla\cdot\mathbf{V}+\nabla\left ( k\nabla T \right ) + \Phi + S_{i} \label{energy_1}\end{equation}}\\
\hline\end{tabular}\caption{Governing equations of flow for a Newtonian fluid}\label{NS_eqt}\end{table}
```

This is the result[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` instead of code snippets. This makes our lives easier and increases the chance of people helping you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To left justify equations one can use `flalign` (see also [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=left%20justify%20equations)).  One can control the gaps around display math using `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayskip`, but even then I had to play with the line spacing.  You will also note that the text doesn't really line up with the subequations.

It should be noted that the equations numbers are set when the table is created, not when it is displayed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}\centering
\abovedisplayskip=0pt
\belowdisplayskip=0pt
\begin{tabular}{ m{3cm} m{10cm} }\hline
Continuity & {\begin{flalign}
\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}+\nabla\cdot\left ( \rho\mathbf{V}\right )=0&&
\label{continuity_1}\end{flalign}}\\[-2ex]
x-momentum\newline\newline y-momentum\newline\newline z-momentum & {\begin{subequations}\begin{flalign}
&\frac{\left ( \partial \rho u\right ) }{\partial t}+\nabla\cdot\left ( \rho u\mathbf{V}\right )
 = -\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}+\nabla\cdot\left ( \mu\nabla u\right ) +S_{Mx}&\\
&\frac{\left ( \partial \rho v\right ) }{\partial t}+\nabla\cdot\left ( \rho v\mathbf{V}\right )
 = -\frac{\partial p}{\partial y}+\nabla\cdot\left ( \mu\nabla v\right ) +S_{My}&\\
&\frac{\left ( \partial \rho w\right ) }{\partial t}+\nabla\cdot\left ( \rho w\mathbf{V}\right )
 = -\frac{\partial p}{\partial z}+\nabla\cdot\left ( \mu\nabla w\right ) +S_{Mz}&
\end{flalign}\label{NS_eq1}\end{subequations}}\\[-2ex]
Energy & {\begin{flalign}
\frac{\left ( \partial \rho e\right ) }{\partial t}+\nabla\cdot\left ( \rho e\mathbf{V}\right )
 =-p\nabla\cdot\mathbf{V}+\nabla\left ( k\nabla T \right ) + \Phi + S_{i}&&
\label{energy_1}\end{flalign}}\\
\hline\end{tabular}\caption{Governing equations of flow for a Newtonian fluid}\label{NS_eqt}\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

This is how I would have done it.  I also made the equation numbers dependent on the table, not the text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcounter{tableeqn}[table]
\renewcommand{\thetableeqn}{\thetable.\arabic{tableeqn}}
\newcounter{tablesubeqn}[tableeqn]
\renewcommand{\thetablesubeqn}{\thetableeqn\alph{tablesubeqn}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}\centering
\stepcounter{table}% for \thetable
\def\arraystretch{2.5}
\begin{tabular}{llr}\hline
Continuity & $\displaystyle
\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}+\nabla\cdot ( \rho\mathbf{V} )=0$ &
\refstepcounter{tableeqn} (\thetableeqn)\label{continuity_1} \\
x-momentum & $\displaystyle
\frac{ ( \partial \rho u ) }{\partial t}+\nabla\cdot ( \rho u\mathbf{V} )
 = -\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}+\nabla\cdot ( \mu\nabla u ) +S_{Mx}$ &
\stepcounter{tableeqn}\refstepcounter{tablesubeqn}(\thetablesubeqn) \\
y-momentum & $\displaystyle
\frac{ ( \partial \rho v ) }{\partial t}+\nabla\cdot ( \rho v\mathbf{V} )
 = -\frac{\partial p}{\partial y}+\nabla\cdot ( \mu\nabla v ) +S_{My}$ &
\refstepcounter{tablesubeqn}(\thetablesubeqn) \\
\newline z-momentum & $\displaystyle
\frac{ ( \partial \rho w ) }{\partial t}+\nabla\cdot ( \rho w\mathbf{V} )
 = -\frac{\partial p}{\partial z}+\nabla\cdot ( \mu\nabla w ) +S_{Mz}$ &
\refstepcounter{tablesubeqn}(\thetablesubeqn) \\
Energy & $\displaystyle
\frac{ ( \partial \rho e ) }{\partial t}+\nabla\cdot ( \rho e\mathbf{V} )
 =-p\nabla\cdot\mathbf{V}+\nabla ( k\nabla T  ) + \Phi + S_{i}$ &
\refstepcounter{tableeqn}(\thetableeqn)\label{energy_1} \\
\hline\end{tabular}
\addtocounter{table}{-1}%
\caption{Governing equations of flow for a Newtonian fluid}\label{NS_eqt}\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo2]

Comment: Do please delete all 13 instances of `\left` and `\right`, resp. None of them are needed. All they do (besides messing up the spacing) is create code clutter.

Comment: @Mico - Not something I normally check.

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to use `tabular` inside a `table` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs}

\newcommand{\pder}[2]{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\rule{\textwidth}{\heavyrulewidth}

\vspace{-\baselineskip}

\begin{flalign}
&\text{Continuity} & \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}+\nabla\cdot (\rho\mathbf{V})=0
&&&\label{continuity_1}
\end{flalign}
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{flalign}
&\text{$x$-momentum}
&\pder{(\rho u)}{t}+\nabla\cdot(\rho u\mathbf{V}) &= -\pder{p}{x}+\nabla\cdot(\mu\nabla u)+S_{Mx}
&&\\
&\text{$y$-momentum}
&\pder{(\rho v)}{t}+\nabla\cdot(\rho v\mathbf{V}) &= -\pder{p}{y}+\nabla\cdot(\mu\nabla v)+S_{My}
&&\\
&\text{$z$-momentum}
&
\pder{(\rho w)}{t}+\nabla\cdot(\rho w\mathbf{V}) &= -\pder{p}{z}+\nabla\cdot(\mu\nabla w)+S_{Mz}
&&
\end{flalign}
\label{NS_eq1}
\end{subequations}
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\begin{flalign}
&\text{Energy}
&\qquad
\pder{(\rho e)}{t}+\nabla\cdot(\rho e\mathbf{V}) =-p\nabla\cdot\mathbf{V}+\nabla(k\nabla T)
  + \Phi + S_{i}
&&&\label{energy_1}
\end{flalign}

\rule{\textwidth}{\heavyrulewidth}

\caption{Governing equations of flow for a Newtonian fluid}\label{NS_eqt}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]