# equation with numbering in table

Tags: tables, equations

i am trying to write some equation with numbering in table like this one [image]

and this is my code

```
\begin{table}[]
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
\toprule
Performance measure & Definition \\ \midrule
energy & \begin{equation} 
E_{(AC,D)}=\sum_{t=1}^{24}E_{AC,t} 
E_{(AC,m)}=\sum_{d=1}^{N}E_{AC,d} 
\label{eq:Bsp_OhmsLaw}
\end{equation} \\
Reference yield &\begin{equation}  Y_{(R)}=\frac{H_{t}(kWh/m^2)}{G(kW/m^2)} 
\end{equation}\\
\noindent
Array yield & \begin{equation} Y_{(A,d)}=\frac{E_{DC,d}}{P_{pv,rated}}  ,Y_{(A,m)}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{d=1}^{N}{Y_{A,d}} \end{equation} \\
Final yield &\begin{equation}  Y_{(F,d)}=\frac{E_{AC,d}}{P_{pv,rated}}  ,Y_{(F,m)}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{d=1}^{N}{Y_{F,d}} \end{equation}\\
Performance ratio &\begin{equation} PR=\frac{Y_{F}}{Y_{R}}
\end{equation} \\
System losses & \begin{equation}L_{S}=Y_{A}-Y_{F}\end{equation} \\
Array capture losses &\begin{equation} L_{c}=Y_{R}-Y_{A}\end{equation} \\
Array efficiency &\begin{equation} eta_{(PV)}=\frac{P_{DC}}{H_{t}*A_{m}}\end{equation} \\
System efficiency &\begin{equation} \eta_{(sys)}=\frac{P_{AC}}{H_{t}*A_{m}} \end{equation} \\
Inverter efficiency & \begin{equation}\frac{P_{AC}}{P_{DC}} \end{equation}\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

and i get this result with many error
[image]
thank you very much.i really need this table

Comment: Will there be other equations (numbered as usual)  in your document? Do you want to be able to reference teh equations in the table?

Comment: Probably related? [Equation and subequations numbering in table environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/386028/134144)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. At the moment we have to guess what packages etc you are using before we can compile your code.

Comment: **Secondly**, in addition to equation numbers do you want *labels* for each equation? I always operate on the principle that you should not give something a number if you do not need to refer to it so I assume yes.

Comment: this is all the usepackage in my document \documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{booktabs} ,about the labels i need for each equation my problem in my code that the number of equation  is near to the equation  ,i want it like the example (first image).thanks

Comment: Rather than putting the document preamble into a comment it is better to edit your question so that we have compliable code. it's also good to cut it down to a minimal preamble:) The main reason for doing this is that sometimes your preamble affects the possible solutions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, the reason why your code does not compile is that you cannot have an `equation` environment inside a table, which is not allowed. You could put each equation inside the table as inline mathematics using `$...$` and you can force the equations to be in display mode, as they would be inside `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}`, by using `$\displaystyle ...$`.

As I think that each equation should have an associated reference,  the nicest way to do this is to define two new column types using the `\newcolumntype` command from the [array](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) package:

```
\newcolumntype{M}{>{$\displaystyle}c<{$}} % mathematics column
\newcommand\AddLabel[1]{\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)\label{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\collectcell\AddLabel}r<{\endcollectcell}}% labeled
```

With these in place the `M`-type columns are put into display stye and the `L`-type columns will have an equation number and the contents of the last table cell become a reference to this equation. To define the `L`-type columns we need to use the [collcell](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/collcell) to extract the contents of the so that we can use them with the `\label` command, which is done by `\AddLabel`. The `\AddLabel` command also increments and prints the equation number.

For example, one of the entries in the table will be:

```
Array efficiency    & \eta_{(PV)}=\frac{P_{DC}}{H_{t}*A_{m}} 
                    & eq:ArrayEfficients \\
```

With this in place the resulting table looks like:

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{{makecell}}
\setcellgapes{3pt}\makegapedcells

\usepackage{array,collcell}
\newcommand\AddLabel[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{equation}% increment equation counter
  (\theequation)% print equation number
  \label{#1}% give the equation a \label
}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\hfil$\displaystyle}X<{$\hfil}} % mathematics column
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\collectcell\AddLabel}r<{\endcollectcell}}

\newcommand\PV{P_{\text{pv,rated}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
 \begin{tabularx}\textwidth{@{}lML@{}}
 \toprule
 \textbf{Performance measure} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Definition}}
                              & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}\\ \midrule
  Energy              & E_{(AC,D)}=\sum_{t=1}^{24}E_{AC,t}, E_{(AC,m)}=\sum_{d=1}^{N}E_{AC,d}
                      & eq:BspOhmsLaw \\
  Reference yield     & Y_{(R)}=\frac{H_{t} (\si{kWh/m^2})}{G (\si{kW/m^2})}
                      & eq:ReferenceYield \\
  Array yield         & Y_{(A,d)}=\frac{E_{DC,d}}{\PV} ,
                        Y_{(A,m)}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{d=1}^{N}{Y_{A,d}}
                      & eq:ArrayYield \\
  Final yield         &  Y_{(F,d)}=\frac{E_{AC,d}}{\PV},
                        Y_{(F,m)}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{d=1}^{N}{Y_{F,d}}
                      & eq:FinalYield\\
  Performance ratio   & PR=\frac{Y_{F}}{Y_{R}}
                      & eq:PerformanceYield \\
  System losses       & L_{S}=Y_{A}-Y_{F}
                      & eq:SystemLosses\\
  Array capture losses& L_{c}=Y_{R}-Y_{A}
                      & eq:SystemLosses\\
  Array efficiency    & \eta_{(PV)}=\frac{P_{DC}}{H_{t}\cdot A_{m}}
                      & eq:ArrayEfficients\\
  System efficiency   & \eta_{(sys)}=\frac{P_{AC}}{H_{t}\cdot A_{m}}
                      & eq:SystemEfficients\\
  Inverter efficiency & \frac{P_{AC}}{P_{DC}}
                      & eq:InverterEfficiency\\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

Here are some nice references:
\ref{eq:BspOhmsLaw}, \ref{eq:ArrayYield} and  \ref{eq:InverterEfficiency}.
\end{document}
```

Notice that

- I have replaced the `tabular` environment with a full width `tabularx` environment using the [tabularx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) package
- I have replaced `P_{pv,rated}` with a macro `\PV`. The most important part of the macro is that it replaces this with `\P_{\text{pv,rated}}` so that "rated" is typeset as a word instead of the product of the variables `r`, `a`, `t`, `e` and `d`. You should probably do the same elsewhere such as with `P_{\text{AC}}` and `P_{\text{DC}}`
- If you don't want the equations typeset in display style then just remove the `\displaystyle` from the `\AddLabel` macro
- We have to use `\multicolumn` for the second and third columns in the table header in order to "turn off" the special processing for the `L` and `M` type columns
- I changed `eta` to `\eta` in equation (8)
- As suggested by @Mico I've put the equations into a `X`-type column so that they take all available space. The definition of the `M`-type has two `\hfil` commands so that the equations are centered within the column
- As suggested by @Zarko I have used the [siunitx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package for the units in equation (2) and I have used the [makecell](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/makecell) package to make the spacing of the different formulas more consistent
- +1 for using [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/)!

Comment: +1. You may want to change the column type of the first column from `l` to `X`, though. Also, the `\centering` instruction has no effect since the width of the `tabularx` environment is set to `\textwidth`; replace `\centering` with `\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}`, maybe? Finally, do consider changing both instances of the multiplicative `*` symbol to `\cdot`.

Comment: +1 For units I would use `siunitx` package: instead of `\frac{H_{t}(kWh/m^2)}{G(kW/m^2)}` is correct `Y_{(R)}=\frac{H_{t}(\si{kWh/m^2})}{G(\si{kW/m^2})}`. For more vertical space can be used `\setcellgapes{5pt}\makegapedcells` from `makecell` package.

Comment: @Mico Thanks I'll edit to fix these.

Comment: @Zarko Thanks I'll edit to fix these.

Answer (score 1):

Modified from --[Equation and subequations numbering in table environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386028/equation-and-subequations-numbering-in-table-environment)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcounter{tableeqn}[table]
\renewcommand{\thetableeqn}{\thetable.\arabic{tableeqn}}
\newcounter{tablesubeqn}[tableeqn]
\renewcommand{\thetablesubeqn}{\thetableeqn\alph{tablesubeqn}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}\centering
\stepcounter{table}% for \thetable
\def\arraystretch{2.5}
\begin{tabular}{llr}\hline
Energy & $E_{(AC,D)}=\sum_{t=1}^{24}E_{AC,t} E_{(AC,m)}=\sum_{d=1}^{N}E_{AC,d}$ &
\refstepcounter{tableeqn} (\thetableeqn)\label{eq:Bsp_OhmsLaw}\\
Continuity & $\displaystyle\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}+\nabla\cdot ( \rho\mathbf{V} )=0$ &
\refstepcounter{tableeqn} (\thetableeqn)\label{continuity_1} \\
Reference yield &$  Y_{(R)}=\frac{H_{t}(kWh/m^2)}{G(kW/m^2)}$ &
\stepcounter{tableeqn}\refstepcounter{tablesubeqn}(\thetablesubeqn) \\
\hline\end{tabular}
\addtocounter{table}{-1}%
\caption{Performance Measures}\label{NS_eqt}\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose two realizations; you don't need `equation` or `tabularx` trickery.

In the last column the numbers are set automatically, you can also specify a `\label`. Note that the trailing `&` is needed anyway.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,array}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!tp]

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  >{$\displaystyle}c<{\vphantom{\sum_{1}{N}}$}
  >{\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)}r
  @{}
}
\toprule
Performance measure & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Definition} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
\midrule
Energy &
  E_{(AC,D)}=\sum_{t=1}^{24}E_{AC,t},
  \qquad
  E_{(AC,m)}=\sum_{d=1}^{N}E_{AC,d} &
  \label{eq:Bsp_OhmsLaw}
\\
Reference yield &
  Y_{(R)}=\frac{H_{t}}{G}\quad \frac{(\si{kWh/m^2})}{(\si{kW/m^2})} &
\\
Array yield & 
  Y_{(A,d)}=\frac{E_{DC,d}}{P_{pv,\mathrm{rated}}},
  \qquad
  Y_{(A,m)}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{d=1}^{N}{Y_{A,d}} &
\\
Final yield &
  Y_{(F,d)}=\frac{E_{AC,d}}{P_{pv,\mathrm{rated}}},
  \qquad
  Y_{(F,m)}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{d=1}^{N}{Y_{F,d}} &
\\
Performance ratio &
  PR=\frac{Y_{F}}{Y_{R}} &
\\
System losses &
  L_{S}=Y_{A}-Y_{F} &
\\
Array capture losses &
  L_{c}=Y_{R}-Y_{A} &
\\
Array efficiency &
  \eta_{(PV)}=\frac{P_{DC}}{H_{t}*A_{m}} &
\\
System efficiency &
  \eta_{(sys)}=\frac{P_{AC}}{H_{t}*A_{m}} &
\\
Inverter efficiency &
  \frac{P_{AC}}{P_{DC}} &
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{table}[!tp]

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  >{$\displaystyle}l<{\vphantom{\sum_{1}{N}}$}
  >{\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)}r
  @{}
}
\toprule
Performance measure & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Definition} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
\midrule
Energy &
  E_{(AC,D)}=\sum_{t=1}^{24}E_{AC,t},
  \qquad
  E_{(AC,m)}=\sum_{d=1}^{N}E_{AC,d} &
  \label{eq:Bsp_OhmsLaw}
\\
Reference yield &
  Y_{(R)}=\frac{H_{t}}{G}\quad \frac{(\si{kWh/m^2})}{(\si{kW/m^2})} &
\\
Array yield & 
  Y_{(A,d)}=\frac{E_{DC,d}}{P_{pv,\mathrm{rated}}},
  \qquad
  Y_{(A,m)}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{d=1}^{N}{Y_{A,d}} &
\\
Final yield &
  Y_{(F,d)}=\frac{E_{AC,d}}{P_{pv,\mathrm{rated}}},
  \qquad
  Y_{(F,m)}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{d=1}^{N}{Y_{F,d}} &
\\
Performance ratio &
  PR=\frac{Y_{F}}{Y_{R}} &
\\
System losses &
  L_{S}=Y_{A}-Y_{F} &
\\
Array capture losses &
  L_{c}=Y_{R}-Y_{A} &
\\
Array efficiency &
  \eta_{(PV)}=\frac{P_{DC}}{H_{t}*A_{m}} &
\\
System efficiency &
  \eta_{(sys)}=\frac{P_{AC}}{H_{t}*A_{m}} &
\\
Inverter efficiency &
  \frac{P_{AC}}{P_{DC}} &
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

Production note: the `\lipsum` commands are used just to make the two tables appear at the top, for convenience of making the picture.

[image]

You might not want to use the standard `equation` counter. Just define a new one and use it instead of `equation` in the column definitions.