# How to prevent `aux` file from generating invalid characters?

Tags: tables, tabularx, multicolumn, auxiliary-files

I’m trying to display a table with:

- Two columns of mathematical expressions
- One column for the equation labels
- Using tabularx

I mostly followed what I saw [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521422/equation-with-numbering-in-table)

However, it’s still giving me trouble.  I looked into the `tabularx` documentation, but it mostly has to do with the adjustable-width of the columns, I could be wrong but I don’t think that’s the problem here.  I have a feeling the problem is in this `newcolumntype` that we’re defining.  But, even after reading the docs, I still can’t see what I’m doing wrong.    Can someone help me determine why this won’t display as just a simple table with two columns of math, and one column of labels?

Here’s my [minimal working example](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\setcellgapes{3pt}\makegapedcells

\usepackage{array,collcell}
\newcommand\AddLabel[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{equation}% increment equation counter
  (\theequation)% print equation number
  \label{#1}% give the equation a \label
}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\hfil$\displaystyle}X<{$\hfil}} % mathematics column
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\collectcell\AddLabel}r<{\endcollectcell}}

\geometry{legalpaper, landscape, margin=0.5in}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\caption {x and y} \label{tab:my_table}
 \begin{tabularx}\textwidth{@{}lML@{}}
 \toprule
 \textbf{Variable 1} & \textbf{Variable 2} & \textbf{label} \\
 \midrule
 $x$                  & $y$ & eq:xy \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Now, when I run this, it generates an aux file like so:

```
relax
\bbl@cs{beforestart}
\@writefile{lot}{\contentsline {table}{\numberline {1}{\ignorespaces x and y}}{1}\protected@file@percent }
\newlabel{tab:my_table}{{1}{1}}
\newlabel{tab:my_table@cref}{{[table][1][]1}{[1][1][]1}}
\newlabel{\textbf  {label}}{{1}{1}}
\newlabel{\textbf  {label}@cref}{{[equation][1][]1}{[1][1][]1}}
\newlabel{eq:xy}{{2}{1}}
\newlabel{eq:xy@cref}{{[equation][2][]2}{[1][1][]1}}
\babel@aux{english}{}
```

And the complaint is

```
(./new_file.aux
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.5 \newlabel{\textbf  {label}}{{1}{1}}
                                       
?
```

Even when I delete the `aux` file, or try to edit it, the problem persists.  What can I do to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: why do you type \textbf{label} in the cell? Use simply label.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer that's a heading it wasn't intended to be a label at all

Comment: @DavidCarlisle but the code grabs it as a label. Ah, I see what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

You have made the L column apply `\label` to each entry but you don't want to do that for the heading so replace `L` by `c` for that cell:

```
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{label}}
```

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle.  I don't totally understand.  I _do_ want a label for each line in the table, but _not_ one label for each cell.  Same as [here] (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521422/equation-with-numbering-in-table).  
Are you saying to replace `\textbf{label}` with `\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{label}}`?  If not, then can you please clarify exactly what needs to be replaced?  
Thanks again.

Comment: yes I mean exactly replace `\textbf{label}` by `\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{label}}`  you want a label for every _data_ line of the table using the entry in that column but you don't want a `\label` for the heading row. Currently you are generating `\label{\textbf{label}}` for that heading.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the intent now.  However, if I literally replace that text exactly, it is still not compiling: 
`! Undefined control sequence.
<inserted text> {@{}lML@{}} \toprule 
                                     \textbf {Variable 1} & \textbf {Variabl...
l.36 \end{tabularx}`
there could be something obvious I'm missing here, but I'm not able to see it.

Comment: HI @DaivdCarlisle.  Thanks for maintaining `tabularx`, (I saw you were a maintainer somewhere in the docs).  I looked at the docs https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx?lang=en but still can't find an answer to the above problem.  Furthermore, I didn't see anything in the docs regarding referencing the table.  Is the answer to the above problem, or anything regarding referencing tables, in the docs?

Comment: @makansij there is nothing I could put in the tabularx doc about this, it isn't related to tabularx it is simply an error in your document, you could get the same in a normal tabular.  The error on `toprule` is completely unrelated That is a command from the `booktabs`  package which you have presumably used without loading the package. Any documentation you have seen that told you about the `toprule` command must have told you abot `booktabs` it isn't a standard latex command.

Comment: I see.  Thanks I've learned a lot from you @DavidCarlisle.