# Labeling equations in a table

Tags: tables, labels, alignment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,} % I added this

\usepackage{verbatim}  % for commenting

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{verbatim}  % for commenting

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\newcommand{\stone}{\theta_1}

\newcommand{\sx}{x}
\newcommand{\sy}{y}

\begin{document}

\begin{table} [tbp]
\centering
  \caption{Equations}
  \label{table:Equations}
  \begin{tabular}{p{0.45in} p{0.5in} p{2.4in}} % {@{}ll@{}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Inputs} & \textbf{Output} & \textbf{Equation} \\
    \midrule
    
   \rotatebox[origin=c]{0}{$\stone$}
    & $\sx$ & \begin{equation}\tag{1}
        0.5 \cos(2\pi\stone) + 0.5
    \end{equation}  \\%\hline

   \rotatebox[origin=c]{0}{$\stone$}
    & $\sy$ & \begin{equation}\tag{2} 0.5\sin(2\pi\stone) + 0.5 
    \end{equation}\\%\hline
    
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This is how the table looks after the above code is executed:

[image]

In this, the columns of the table are not aligned properly. I need the equations to be labeled.

Comment: What's the reason for `\rotatebox` with a zero angle?

Answer (score 2):

Why `\rotatebox[origin=c]{0}{$\stone$}`?

You can manually step the `equation` counter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}

% not sure what's the purpose of these commands
\newcommand{\stone}{\theta_1}
\newcommand{\sx}{x}
\newcommand{\sy}{y}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering

\caption{Equations}
\label{table:Equations}

\begin{tabular}{lllr}
\toprule
\textbf{Inputs} & \textbf{Output} & \textbf{Equation} \\
\midrule
$\stone$ & $\sx$ & $0.5 \cos(2\pi\stone) + 0.5$ &
  \refstepcounter{equation}\thetag{\theequation}\label{eq:first}
\\
$\stone$ & $\sy$ & $0.5\sin(2\pi\stone) + 0.5$ &
  \refstepcounter{equation}\thetag{\theequation}\label{eq:second}
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\eqref{eq:first} and \eqref{eq:second}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Whether something like this is better, or something like WinnieNotThePooh's answer might depend on how compact you want the table, but if you want something more compact, you could just manually increase the equation counter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,} % I added this

\usepackage{verbatim}  % for commenting

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{verbatim}  % for commenting

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand{\stone}{\theta_1}

\newcommand{\sx}{x}
\newcommand{\sy}{y}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[tbp]
\centering
  \caption{Equations}
  \label{table:Equations}
  \begin{tabular}{p{0.45in} p{0.5in} p{2.2in} r@{}} % {@{}ll@{}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Inputs} & \textbf{Output} & \textbf{Equation} & \\
    \midrule
    $\stone$
    & $\sx$
    & $0.5 \cos(2\pi\stone) + 0.5$
    & \refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)\label{eq:one}
    \\
    $ \stone$
    & $\sy$
    & $0.5\sin(2\pi\stone) + 0.5$
    & \refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)\label{eq:two}
    \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You should still be able to refer to them with `\ref`, etc., in the normal way.

[image: equation table]

Answer (score 1):

With use of the `tabularray` packages: two possible solutions

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath, booktabs, counter, varwidth}


\begin{document}
\addtocounter{equation}{-1}
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {*{2}{Q[l,m, mode=math]}
                             X[c,m, mode=dmath]
                             Q[r, cmd=\refstepcounter{equation}]},
              row{1} = {font=\bfseries, c, mode=text},
             measure = vbox,
             }
    \toprule
Inputs      &   Output  &   Equation    &           \\
    \midrule
\theta_1    &   y   &   %
                        0.5 \cos(2\pi\theta_1) + 0.5  & \thetag{\theequation}\label{eq:first}   \\
\theta_1    &   y   &   %
                        0.5 \cos(2\pi\theta_1) + 0.5  & \thetag{\theequation}\label{eq:second}  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}

\medskip
\eqref{eq:first} and \eqref{eq:second}

\vspace{3ex}
\begingroup
    \setlength\abovedisplayskip{-1ex}
    \setlength\belowdisplayskip{-1ex}
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {*{2}{Q[l,m, mode=math]}
                             X[c,m]},
             row{1} = {font=\bfseries, c, mode=text},
           row{2-Y} = {rowsep=-2ex},
            measure = vbox,
             }
    \toprule
Inputs      &   Output  &   Equation        \\
    \midrule
\theta_1    &   y   &   \begin{equation}\label{eq:third}
                        0.5 \cos(2\pi\theta_1) + 0.5
                        \end{equation}      \\
\theta_1    &   y   &   \begin{equation}\label{eq:fourth}
                        0.5 \cos(2\pi\theta_1) + 0.5
                        \end{equation}      \\
\theta_1    &   y   &   \begin{equation}\label{eq:fifth}
                        0.5 \cos(2\pi\theta_1) + 0.5
                        \end{equation}      \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\endgroup

\medskip
\eqref{eq:third}, \eqref{eq:fourth}  and \eqref{eq:fifth}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` inside a table cell. If you want it to look like a displayed equation, you can do this:

```
... & \(\displaystyle 0.5 \cos(2\pi\stone) + 0.5 \)
```

---

**But You can try something like that:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,} % I added this

\usepackage{verbatim}  % for commenting

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{verbatim}  % for commenting

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\newcommand{\stone}{\theta_1}

\newcommand{\sx}{x}
\newcommand{\sy}{y}

\begin{document}

\begin{table} [tbp]
\centering
  \caption{Equations}
  \label{table:Equations}
  \begin{tabular}{p{0.45in} p{0.5in} p{2.4in}} % {@{}ll@{}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Inputs} & \textbf{Output} & \textbf{Equation} \\
    \midrule
    
   \rotatebox[origin=c]{0}{$\stone$}
    & $\sx$ &  \parbox{4cm}{\begin{equation} 0.5 \cos(2\pi\stone) + 0.5 \end{equation}} \\%\hline

   \rotatebox[origin=c]{0}{$\stone$}
    & $\sy$ &  \parbox{4cm}{\begin{equation} 0.5\sin(2\pi\stone) + 0.5 \end{equation}}\\%\hline
    
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

So, as You understand enumerate equations in table isn't nice idea but I would recomend You to look at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521422/equation-with-numbering-in-table) and make something like that)